# Complicated layout in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made this complicated layout in bootstrap but, the point is when I remove to image below on the right side, all other images changing smaller.

How can I have this always same size?

I tried to work with numbers for width and height but the result was bad!
The number of images will change based on the titles so I might have 3 images or 2 or 5.

Please help me!

Before removing
After removing

```css
.container-fluid .expo {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.expoinfo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}
.expoinfo h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
.bigimg {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.bigimg img {
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  height: 100%;
}
.colthumb {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
.thumbnail {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-style: none;
}
.thumbnail img {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-style: none;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid expo">
  <div class="row expoinfo">
    <section class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
      <h3>title</h3>

      <div class="bigimg col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <a href="http://fakeimg.pl/700x400/" title="">
          <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/600x600/" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="colthumb col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="http://fakeimg.pl/700x400/" title="">
            <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/300x300/" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="colthumb col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="http://fakeimg.pl/700x400/" title="">
            <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/300x300/" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="colthumb col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="http://fakeimg.pl/700x400/" title="">
            <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/300x300/" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="colthumb col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="http://fakeimg.pl/700x400/" title="">
            <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/300x300/" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what's is the problem? What image on the right side and then what images are smaller?

Comment: Sorry, I attached some image but I am not sure why is not showing in the post! I will edit the post and try to attached images again.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ccfdu7q8/

Comment: Look at this links

http://i.stack.imgur.com/V0RGb.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/kTobr.png

Comment: So this is what you want or don't want? I still don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: Thank you Bojan,
I don't want any change in the size when I remove 2 images from the right side below.
Now after I removing those two images from the right everything got smaller, which I don't want this happen.

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/8qthz6ygf/
Have a look at this image. Might help you understand my point.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found my answer!

```
    <div class="row">
     <section class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
     <h3>title</h3>
      <div class=" thumbcol col-md-4 col-lg-6">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/300x300/" alt="Thumbnail Image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" thumbcol col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/300x300/" alt="Thumbnail Image"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" thumbcol col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/300x300/" alt="Thumbnail Image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class=" thumbcol col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/300x300/" alt="Thumbnail Image"></div>
      </div>
     </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you made didn't include `bootstrap.css` even though it was using bootstrap's classes.

See updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2aLdmvw4/

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Martin,

Please have a look at this link https://jsfiddle.net/2aLdmvw4/

Can you see the different between the one on top and the one on the bottom?

Comment: Sorry, I left the wrong link in my previous comment. Please check this one.
https://jsfiddle.net/2aLdmvw4/1/

Try to wide the preview section as much as you can to see both top and bottom sections.

Comment: Is this what you were going for? https://jsfiddle.net/2aLdmvw4/2/
Every `row` class needs to be inside another element with `container` class.